# Is There A Way I Could Make My Pong Ball Move Depending Where It Hits On The Paddle? Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I coded the simple pong game below using pygame.

Is there a way for me to make my ball move depending on where the ball hits on the player's paddle, sort of like a skill-based game ? Currently the ball just bounce on the paddle like if it were a moving vertical wall.

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 600, 500

class Speed:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.color = color
        self.speed = Speed(0,5)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)

    def up(self):
        if self.rect.y < self.speed.y:
            return
        self.rect.move_ip(0, -self.speed.y)

    def down(self):
        if self.rect.y + self.speed.y > WIDTH:
            return
        self.rect.move_ip(0, self.speed.y)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


class Ball:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.color = color
        self.speed = Speed(5,5)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)

    def move(self):
        nextx = self.rect.x + self.speed.x
        nexty = self.rect.y + self.speed.y
        if nextx <= 0 or nextx >= WIDTH: self.speed.x *= -1
        if nexty <= 0 or nexty >= HEIGHT: self.speed.y *= -1
        self.rect.move_ip(self.speed.x,self.speed.y)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, self.color, self.rect.center,10)



pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

# title
pygame.display.set_caption("pong")

white = (255,255,255)
player1 = Paddle(30,150,10,120,white)
player2 = Paddle(570,150,10,120,white)
ball1 = Ball(290,200,20,20,white)

FPS = 60

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
playing = True

pygame.event.get()

while playing:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            playing = False
            break;

    ball1.move()

    # ball hit paddle
    if ball1.rect.colliderect(player1.rect) or ball1.rect.colliderect(player2.rect):
        ball1.speed.x *= -1

    # key event
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:   player2.up()
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]: player2.down()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:    player1.up()
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:    player1.down()

    window.fill((0,0,0))
    player2.draw()
    player1.draw()
    ball1.draw()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Are you able to get the paddles x and y coordinates? If so you could do some math and find the normal vector that points away from the paddle which is the direction you want to ball to move towards.

Comment: my paddle one position is 30,150    and my paddle2 position is 570,150 I am not sure how to apply it tho

Comment: I see policy cops are following their usual "be rude" policy. The closing motive is especially bad: more focused ? The question can certainly be improved, for instance providing working minimal code, but to be more focused than what is asked it should probably include the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough, and there is more than one way to do it:

There are actually two separate problems to solve. The first one is detecting where the ball has hit the paddle. The second one is making the bounce of the ball depend of the place where the paddle was hit.

We can for instance divide the paddle in threa parts top, middle and bottom and define a different behavior depending of the position hit.

- ball hit paddle in the top part: the ball will be reflected up (vertical speed goes up)
- ball hit paddle in the middle part: the vertical speed is unchanged
- ball hit paddle in the bottom part: the ball will got down

This behavior was often seen on actual pong games in the 80's.

This choice would for instance give the code below:

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 600, 500

class Speed:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.color = color
        self.speed = Speed(0,5)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)

    def pad_top(self):
        return pygame.Rect(self.rect.x,self.rect.y,
                           self.rect.width,self.rect.height//4)

    def pad_middle(self):
        return pygame.Rect(self.rect.x,self.rect.y+rect.height//4,
                           self.rect.width,self.rect.height//2)

    def pad_bottom(self):
        return pygame.Rect(self.rect.x,self.rect.y+3*self.rect.height//4,
                           self.rect.width,self.rect.height//4)

    def up(self):
        if self.rect.y < self.speed.y:
            return
        self.rect.move_ip(0, -self.speed.y)

    def down(self):
        if self.rect.y + self.speed.y > WIDTH:
            return
        self.rect.move_ip(0, self.speed.y)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


class Ball:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.color = color
        self.speed = Speed(5,5)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)

    def move(self):
        nextx = self.rect.x + self.speed.x
        nexty = self.rect.y + self.speed.y
        if nextx <= 0 or nextx >= WIDTH: self.speed.x *= -1
        if nexty <= 0 or nexty >= HEIGHT: self.speed.y *= -1
        self.rect.move_ip(self.speed.x,self.speed.y)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, self.color, self.rect.center,10)



pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

# title
pygame.display.set_caption("pong")

white = (255,255,255)
player1 = Paddle(30,150,10,120,white)
player2 = Paddle(570,150,10,120,white)
ball1 = Ball(290,200,20,20,white)

FPS = 60

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
playing = True

pygame.event.get()

while playing:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            playing = False
            break;

    ball1.move()

    # ball hit paddle
    for player in [player1, player2]:
        if ball1.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
            ball1.speed.x *= -1
            # Ball collide upper part of paddle
            if ball1.rect.colliderect(player.pad_top()):
                # Ball go up
                ball1.speed.y = -abs(ball1.speed.y)
            # Ball collide lower part of paddle
            elif ball1.rect.colliderect(player.pad_bottom()):
                # Ball fo down
                ball1.speed.y = abs(ball1.speed.y)

    # key event
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:   player2.up()
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]: player2.down()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:    player1.up()
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:    player1.down()

    window.fill((0,0,0))
    player2.draw()
    player1.draw()
    ball1.draw()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

But this choice is of course arbitrary. We could define some behavior depending for instance from the distance between ball and middle of paddle. This will lead to slightly more complicated math (not that much), but the underlying idea is very similar.

We could also try to make the ball depends on the speed of the paddle, this would be more complex as really the variable defining the speed of the paddle is not it's actual speed as it is enable only when keys are pressed, before doing anything we should evaluate the actual speed of the paddle or something like that.

Actualy any crazy idea of behavior would do, basically we are simulating arbitrary laws of physics. Just think how you want the ball should behave and the rest is just code.

Comment: so I could say if paddle1.top > 100: then ball.y -= ball.speed? something like that?

Comment: Yes. Something like
    paddletop = pygame.Rect(playerman.x,playerman.y-playerman.height/2,playerman.height/4,playerman.width)
    if ball1.rect.colliderect(paddletop): ball1.vely = -abs(vel1.vely)

Comment: This will force the ball to go up when the ball hits the top of the paddle

Comment: `if playerman.rect.top == pygame.Rect(playerman.x,playerman.y-playerman.height/2,playerman.height/4,playerman.width):
        ball1.yvel *= -1` this is what I have tried but nothing seems to work

Comment: Try the code I added in my answer, your condition isn't right: it should involve both ball position and player position (paddle). Also using equality is too strict, it would involve pixel position equality.

Comment: oh I fixed something that wasnt working but still nothing is happening when the ball collides with the rect it just goes throw it  [video](https://gyazo.com/d7d46aacad55d576395f25625b3d7032) and this is the script [script](https://gyazo.com/2e1893d15933126b14257862938ba9fa)

Comment: From the video it looks like an effect of the way you manage the collision. The balls seems to move throughthe paddle, henceforth the collision is missed. It should be easy to fix, but please provide a complete minimal working code.

Comment: oh sorry about that  https://pastebin.com/19jStcUb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216799/discussion-between-kriss-and-habib-ismail).